# Why does this error message appear /before/ the command?

Tags: windows, cmd

My script:

```
echo hello
FOR /F %%G IN temp\clist.txt DO type %%G
```

The output:

```
S:\TLIB admin\Sets' choicelist orphans>echo hello
hello
temp\clist.txt was unexpected at this time.

S:\TLIB admin\Sets' choicelist orphans>FOR /F %G IN temp\clist.txt DO type %G

S:\TLIB admin\Sets' choicelist orphans>
```

Comment: Note that this question about order of the output, not how to properly use `FOR` command.

Comment: Sorry, deleted unrelated answer.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  If the question is about invalid syntax and why it behaves the way it does then the OP hasn't made the aim of the question clear, or the question itself clear.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a question about code syntax that is invalid - asking why doesn't it work.

Comment: @foxidrive "it is a question about code syntax that is invalid - asking why doesn't it work". No. The question is not asking why it doesn't work. It is asking "Why does this error message appear /before/ the command?"

Answer (score 1):

This assumes that the temp folder is located in the current working directory.

```
@echo off
echo hello
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%G IN ("temp\clist.txt") DO echo %%G
```

Or you could use this if you just want to `type` the file.

```
type "temp\clist.txt"
```

Comment: Perhaps you could read the code in your question and the code in mine.  Yours doesn't work as the syntax is wrong.  If you're asking why incorrect syntax doesn't work then you're not in the right forum.

Comment: This is the correct answer, though (in my opinion). Because if I read the above correct, the error _is not output first at all_, merely the `echo` command is, which is correct behavior given that no `@echo off` is in the original snippet. That's irrespective of the errors (or their cause) later.

Comment: @foxidrive "If you're asking why incorrect syntax doesn't work" I am not. Please read the question.

Comment: @Damon "the error is not output first at all," No. The error message appears first i.e. before the input like that causes it. And in fact even before the prompt that invites that input line.

Comment: @ChrisJJ: I see: "echo hello" followed by its output ("hello"). And then, as expected, the error message of the offending line. But maybe I don't understand your issue correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Why the error is shown *before* the command? Because the problem raises not at the command execution, but at command parse.

When the parser reads the line and tries to convert it to a valid internal representation of what the line is intended to do, it sees the `for` command but the line can not be interpreted as a valid command (as stated in other answers/comments), so parser outputs the error description to stderr (by default the console), and, if echo is on, the literal that can not be interpreted is sent to stdout, but not executed, as it has been discarded by the parser.